# Php 7 error for a simple form getting Object of class mysqli could not be converted to int

Tags: php-7

The code gets error saying  Object of class mysqli could not be converted to int. When i try to load the page i get this error,i checked other questions but it was not helpful

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "coinlion");
if ($conn == 0) {
    echo "could not connect";
} else {
    mysqli_select_db("coinlion");
    echo "connected";
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <style>
        #newlink {
            width: 600px
        }
    </style>
    <div id="newlink">
        <div>
            <table border=0>
                <tr>
                    <td> Link URL:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="linkurl" value="" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Link Description:</td>
                    <td><textarea name="linkdesc" cols="50" rows="5" required></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit1">
        <input type="reset" name="reset1">
    </p>
```

php code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
    $linkurl = $_POST['linkurl'];
    $linkdesc = $_POST['linkdesc'];
    mysqli_query($conn, "insert into  
      test(linkurl,linkdesc)values('$_POST[linkurl]','$_POST[linkdesc]')");
    echo "data inserted";
}
?>
```

Comment: but why removing if($conn==0) the code works, whats the issue behind it?anyone knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the issue was with the line    if($conn==0) ,This value was taken as an integer so the error occured and an Connection variable to Mysqli_select_db was missing , after fixing it , the code ran successfully